# Performance of Apache James Mail Server is poor on Windows

Tags: java, windows, performance, email, james

I built mail server using Apache James 2.3.2 and I found James works fine on Linux. Howerver, its performance on windows is very poor. In case of Linux, James can send bout 1000 messages per minute. But on Windows, it can only send about 12 or 13 messages per minute. I use JRE 1.7 64bit on both OS. Is this normal? What should I do in Windows to make it better?

Answer (score 0):

Performance has been improved a lot in last release (beta), I suggest to use [james-3.0-beta4](http://james.apache.org/server/3/) since it is in production in many sites. James developers are focused in 3.0.